# Is calling std::vector::size() as fast as reading a variable?

Tags: c++, performance, compiler-optimization, stdvector, loop-invariant

I have do an extensive calculation on a big vector of integers. The vector size is not changed during the calculation. The size of the vector is frequently accessed by the code. What is faster in general:

- using the `vector::size()` function or
- using a helper constant `vectorSize` for storing the size of the vector?

I know that compilers usually inline the `size()` function when setting the proper compiler flags, however, this is not guaranteed.

Comment: Using the local variable is obviously not going to be any slower. If the actual speed difference matters to you - time it.

Comment: It smells a lot like premature optimization.

Comment: @NomeN, this is more like avoiding premature pessimization.  The OP already knows his vector is huge, so `size()` would be called a lot.

Comment: I agree that putting vector::size() in a loop condition is something I'd routinely take out because I see no reason it's better not to.

Comment: It does not matter. Even the answers that say that it will not be *as fast* admit that it will just take an extra substraction from two pointers. Even if the compiler does not optimize it, does that really ammount to anything at all? I doubt it. If in doubt: measure.

Comment: @Autopulated: compiler right-shifts me?

Comment: @John not if I overloaded operator>>(compiler, you) ;)

Comment: The only guarantee provided by the standard is that size() on any container will not have a complexity greater than O(n). There is no better guarantee provided for std::vector

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Interesting question.

So, what's going to happened ? Well if you debug with gdb you'll see something like 3 member variables (names are not accurate):

- `_M_begin`: pointer to the first element of the dynamic array
- `_M_end`: pointer one past the last element of the dynamic array
- `_M_capacity`: pointer one past the last element that could be stored in the dynamic array

The implementation of `vector<T,Alloc>::size()` is thus usually reduced to:

```
return _M_end - _M_begin;  // Note: _Mylast - _Myfirst in VC 2008
```

Now, there are 2 things to consider when regarding the actual optimizations possible:

- will this function be inlined ? Probably: I am no compiler writer, but it's a good bet since the overhead of a function call would dwarf the actual time here and since it's templated we have all the code available in the translation unit
- will the result be cached (ie sort of having an unnamed local variable): it could well be, but you won't know unless you disassemble the generated code

In other words:

- If you store the `size` yourself, there is a good chance it will be as fast as the compiler could get it.
- If you do not, it will depend on whether the compiler can establish that nothing else is modifying the `vector`; if not, it cannot cache the variable, and will need to perform memory reads (L1) every time.

It's a micro-optimization. In general, it will be unnoticeable, either because the performance does not matter or because the compiler will perform it regardless. In a critical loop where the compiler does not apply the optimization, it can be a significant improvement.

Comment: "Will the result be cached?" That's a question which can have 2 answers even within a single function. Compilers are quite good at figuring out whether and where they have enough registers to save an intermediate result.

Comment: @MSalters: I couldn't agree more. And in particular if the compiler decides there isn't enough space, then introducing a spurious variable may not yield any improvement.

Comment: There are some situations where using a local variable is significantly faster. For example, I had a `Pintool` with a loop over a `30000` element vector that was called before the execution of each basic block of the traced program. For a single run, after 8 minutes even half of the program was not finished. When I replaced `size()` with a variable, the execution time reduced to 80 seconds.

Comment: @TheAhmad: Indeed. As all micro-optimizations it rarely is worth it, but it can sometimes have dramatic effect -- I have altered the conclusion to better reflect this. Note that if possible you should use `for (auto& e : vec)` to iterate over the vector, and you will get the most optimal form of iteration.

Comment: In the asm, it also has to divide by `sizeof(T)` after doing a `sub` instruction on the pointers which gives the distance in bytes.  For power-of-2 sizes, this is a right shift, but it's still two instructions.  For non-power-of-2 objects (typically structs/classes), it needs a multiply and at least a shift, unless it can optimize away use of `size` and actually just increment / compare pointers.

Comment: The other cost is that if anything in your loop modifies a `T*` object (not a pointed-to `T`, but e.g. deref of a `T**`), the compiler usually can't be sure that didn't alias with the `std::vector` control block, so it has to reload the begin and end members before redoing subtraction.  L1d cache hits are fast, but it's still extra instructions for the pipeline, but it defeats auto-vectorization because it can't assume `.begin` is loop-invariant, and the loop end-point could change mid-loop.  (Current compilers can only vectorize loops where the trip-count is computable ahead of the 1st iter.)

Comment: Of course, just hoisting uses of `.size()` manually won't fix that, you'd also need to hoist access to `.begin()`.  For example by using `for (auto& e : vec)`.   Or you'd need `__restrict` (which many C++ compilers support as an extension) or something to tell the compiler the `std::vector` object's pointers won't be accessed by other code.  It's more of a problem for `gcc -fno-strict-aliasing`, or for MSVC, because then any pointer deref could be modifying a pointer, not just `T**` pointers.

Answer (score 13):

As I understand the 1998 C++ specification, `vector<T>::size()` takes constant time, not linear time. So, this question likely boils down to whether it's faster to read a local variable than calling a function that does very little work.

I'd therefore claim that **storing your vector's `size()` in a local variable will speed up your program by a small amount**, since you'll only call that function (and therefore the small constant amount of time it takes to execute) once instead of many times.

Comment: I think that if your compiler isn't smart enough to inline `vector::size`, the performance of any code using standard template containers will be so desperately awful that removing a few calls to `size` won't help. So it's not really a function call overhead. If it was, what about all the calls to `operator[]`, or `operator*` on an iterator? We could assume they're slow too, and iterate over the vector using a pointer starting with `&vec[0]`. If you don't trust your implementation of `std::vector`, best just to write in C instead of C++...

Comment: That said, you may well be right that it would be a small speedup, just not because of the inlining issue the questioner is worried about. For instance, maybe `size` hits memory every time (if the compiler can't prove to itself that the size won't change), whereas using a local variable allows the compiler to keep the size in a register (if you have enough registers). You never know, basically.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Well pointed out. The real time saving (even if it's very small) of course would result from calling the function only once instead of many times, not from the fact that the function call mechanism itself is more expensive than reading a variable. -- However, I wouldn't want to rely on an optimising compiler to take the function call outside of the loop if I can easily do this myself.

Answer (score 9):

> Performance of vector::size() : is it
>   as fast as reading a variable?

Probably not.

> Does it matter

Probably not.

Unless the work you're doing per iteration is tiny (like one or two integer operations) the overhead will be insignificant.

Answer (score 7):

In every implementation I've, seen `vector::size()` performs a subtraction of `end()` and `begin()`, ie its not as fast as reading a variable.

When implementing a vector, the implementer has to make a choice between which shall be fastest, `end()` or `size(),` ie storing the number of initialized elements or the pointer/iterator to the element after the last initialized element.
In other words; iterate by using iterators.

If you are worried of the size() performance, write your index based for loop like this;

```
for (size_t i = 0, i_end = container.size(); i < i_end; ++i){
// do something performance critical
}
```

Comment: "In every implementation I've, seen vector::size() performs a subtraction of end() and begin(), ie its not as fast as reading a variable." -- yes but the compiler may still take that outside the loop in theory, or otherwise monkey about with the C++ code you are looking at.

Comment: True, compilers often find's these kind of optimizations. But if it's a hotspot, I would still make the optimization by myself.

Answer (score 4):

I always save `vector.size()` in a local variable (if the the size doesn't change inside the loop!).
Calling it on each iteration vs. saving it in a local variable can be faster.
At least, that's what I experienced.
I can't give you any real numbers, as I tested this a very long time ago. However from what I can recall, it made a noticeable difference (however potentially only in debug mode), especially when nesting loops.

And to all the people complaining about micro-optimization:
It's a single additional line of code that introduces no downsides.

Answer (score 0):

You could write yourself a functor for your loop body and call it via `std::for_each`.  It does the iteration for you, and then your question becomes moot.  However, you're introducing a function call (that may or may not get inlined) for every loop iteration, so you'd best profile it if you're not getting the performance you expect.

Comment: You're asssuming that size() is used just in the loop condition. What if each iteration calls `foo(vec[i], vec.size()-i)` ? You can't make that call using `for_each`.

Answer (score 0):

Always get a profile of your application before looking at this sort of micro optimization. Remember that even if it performs a subtraction, the compiler could still easily optimize it in many ways that would negate any performance loss.